# Can't create database named "delete"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using the following to create a database:

```
use master 

IF DB_ID(N'delete') IS NULL 
    CREATE DATABASE delete
```

but get an error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'delete'

because `delete` is a reserved word. But is there no way of creating a database named "delete"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are seeing, `delete` is a reserved word in most SQL databases.

You *could* quote the identifier. In T-SQL, which you seem to be using, you would do this with square brackets:

```
CREATE DATABASE [delete];
```

*But* I would not recommend that. From thereon, you will need to quote the database name each and every time you use it - if you fail to do that, you might encounter non-intuitive error messages. As I see it, there are enough words in the English language that we can avoid the very small subset of SQL reserved words (I would extend that to keywords too).

How about this, for example:

```
CREATE DATABASE db_delete;
```

Comment: And i can also put a check before creation to not allow certain database names.

Comment: @Debbie.S - It sounds like you are creating database names based on some input, e.g. a user supplied name. To some extent you can avoid issues by using [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql). A database name must follow the rules for an [identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15), but that doesn't mean that all of the allowable names are good choices. It may make sense to use a domain appropriate prefix, e.g. `BowlingLeague_`, to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Delete is a reserved word, try `[delete]` instead of `delete` or choose a better database name e.g. `itemstodelete`?